# How can I fix it so that only friends can send me message on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Someone disturbing me by sending message on Facebook. How can I fix it so that only friends can send me message on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct setting to set only for friends as of now. Here is what you can do:

- Go to your profile
- Click on top right "Quick Help" (?)
- Click on "who can contact me" option
- Set "Friends of friends"

So only "Friends of friends" will be able to message you.

If someone who you're not connected with on Facebook sends you a message, you'll receive a [message request](https://www.facebook.com/help/936247526442073). In the message request there will be two options:

- **Accept** to open the conversation
- **Delete** to remove the request

If you delete a message request, you won't be able to see the message again. If you want to chat with someone who sent a request you deleted, you can send them a message. Your message will go to their message requests.

If someone is bothering you, you can [block message](https://www.facebook.com/help/1682395428676916?helpref=about_content).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an option anymore. The third step no longer exists?

Comment: The option no longer exists.